# Count of unique values in two distinct array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Assuming that arr1 and arr2 are two different gates we have to find the count of employees who entered from different gates.

I tried to solve this question but output should be `{ Cognizant: 1, Infosys: 1, Wipro: 2 }`

instead I am getting `{ Cognizant: 1, Infosys: 2, Wipro: 3 }`

```
const arr1 = [{
    empId: 1,
  employer: 'Infosys',
}, {
    empId: 2,
  employer: 'Wipro',
},
{
    empId: 3,
  employer: 'Cognizant',
}]

 
 const arr2 = [{
    empId: 1,
  employer: 'Infosys',
}, {
    empId: 2,
  employer: 'Wipro',
}, {
    empId: 3,
  employer: 'Wipro'
}]
```

My approach

```
const arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2]
console.log(arr3)

const output = arr3.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
  if(acc[curr.employer])
  {
  acc[curr.employer] = ++acc[curr.employer]
  }
  else {
  acc[curr.employer] = 1
  }
  return acc

},{})
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Can you clarify a few points?  Are you trying to find out how many employees entered through both gates?  If so, are you trying to get that sum by company?  Why does empID 3 have two different employers?  Are you trying to find out how many gates are used by each company?  Are the empIDs relevant at all?  Why do you expect Infosys to be 1, when it is present in both arrays?  If you are tracking unique gates usage by company I would expect `{ Cognizant: 1, Infosys: 2, Wipro: 2 } `, since InfoSys and Wipro are in both arrays, and Cognizant is only in one.

Answer (score 0):

- Using the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), join the two arrays. Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the resulting list while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the employer is the `key` and the list of employee ids is the `value`. This will result in grouping the employee ids per employer.
- Using [`Map#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the resulting pairs while updating an object where the employer/gate is the `key` and the number of its unique ids (using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)) is the `value`.

```js
const 
  arr1 = [ { empId: 1, employer: 'Infosys' }, { empId: 2, employer: 'Wipro',
}, { empId: 3, employer: 'Cognizant' } ],
  arr2 = [ { empId: 1, employer: 'Infosys', }, { empId: 2, employer: 'Wipro' }, { empId: 3, employer: 'Wipro' } ];
  
const employerEmployeesMap = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((map, { empId, employer }) => 
  map.set(employer, [...(map.get(employer) ?? []), empId])
, new Map);

const gatesCount = [...employerEmployeesMap.entries()].reduce((map, [ gate, employeeIds ]) => ({
  ...map,
  [gate]: (new Set(employeeIds)).size
}), {});

console.log(gatesCount);
```